# X and Y homing issues

Tags: marlin, firmware, y-axis, x-axis, homing

I get an `error: printer halted. (kill() called!` Any time I home my machine's X or Y axis. I have just installed a 3D touch auto bed level sensor, ironically it works fine. I was using Sprinter firmware but it doesn't support auto bed level, so thus I'm using Marlin. I am using the latest version of Marlin and it gave me nothing but issues, printer wouldn't move or home at all. I used the latest Marlin 1.1.x bug fix edition (1.1.9) and now everything is working correctly except X and Y homing, the machine throws the `error: printer halted. (kill() called!` on Repetier-Host.

When I use the `M119` command all endstops (optical, not mechanical) show as open unless triggered, the endstops are working correctly. When I home the X and or Y it will do as it should and stop when it hits the endstop but that is when the errors pop up and the printer freezes/no longer to gives commands without disconnecting and reconnecting to the printer again.

If I home my Z axis it will deploy the probe and come down and touch the bed 2x and no error code and I can still manually move the printer around with the program movements after homing Z axis. I'm not sure what would cause this to happen only on X and Y but any help would be appreciated.

I use Repetier-Host but I downloaded Printrun just to see what would happen and it shows the exact same effect/errors. I also tried the Marlin bugfix 2.0 and it gave the same errors too.

Comment: qould you mind telling the verion number of your marlin (the one you downloaded)? "latest version" becomes a wrong information within short weeks often.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE, btw!

Comment: @Trish The latest version of the 1.1.x branch will always be 1.1.9 as of sometime last year. X) They abandoned that branch, new developments take place in branch 2.

Comment: all of the versions i used were downlaoded with in the last 3 days, I've tried all the verisons they have listed.

Comment: Also, the board I'm using is a ramps 1.4 all of the electronics I use are the most basic 3D printing stuff you can find online. I also tried removing the auto bed level and its settings to test and see if it was the Z probe causing the issue and it did not change any thing. I'm assuming its some sort of homing setting or maybe possibly a endstop setting but the end stops seem to work correctly.

Comment: I also did forget to mention I am using optical endstops not mechanical.

Comment: I made a small amount of progress. When I turn on pull ups for X and Y min I can now home the printer with out error codes, but If i try to print some thing I get the error code again.

theres a catch though, If I home the Y axis first it will give me the error code, if I home X thenY no error code unless I try to print.

Comment: @user3335963 I've added a bounty to attract more people to help you out. In the mean time, please update the question by [edit]; comments are not really meant for prolonged information addition and storage or discussion. The better. more complete the question, the more chance you get an appropriate answer.

Comment: @user3335963 Please add images of the optical endstops and the wiring of the endstops (also wiring to the board). This is e.g. interesting to see whether you have wired it incorrectly and induce a short circuit.

Comment: also include information if your optical sensors are Normally Open or Normally Closed.

Comment: Please help us help you! Please add the requested data into your question by [edit] and ping Trish or 0scar by leaving a comment where you put the @ in front of the user name to give him a notification! This does not sound as a configuration problem, but a hardware problem. You may also add a link to your configuration.h file if you want us to check it for you.

Comment: at least give us a wiring diagram, labeling which input/output is wired to which sensor input/output and where your optical sensors get their power from. Also, the specs of the optical sensors (working voltage) would be a necessary information

Answer (score 1):

Without the images of how you connected the endstops, the best guess for your problem is that the endstops cause a short circuit, once pressed, the microprocessor trips and shuts down. If you provide more information, other people may even add better answers based on your added information.

E.g. how is everything connected at both sides of the cable (board and endstop), does the message occur when you press an endstop, maybe it is even wise to add a link to your configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize I should have got back with you guys sooner. I downloaded a fresh copy of the Marlin firmware again and pulled up the Sprinter config.H folder. Since the firmwares are very similar I was able to just glance at my Sprinter firmware and noticed certain endstops for my optical endstops required "pull ups" to correctly work. I thought I had tried this before but either I did some thing wrong the first time or I didn't save the changes, who knows. Thanks to every one trying to help.